# Receive response messages to a particular number - Twilio

Tags: php, sms, response, twilio

How can I get the SMS replies (reply messages to an SMS send from twilio) to a particular number? Now when I reply to a message I'm seeing the messages in my twilio account. I want to get those response SMS to one particular mobile number.

How can I do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can get all the messages sent to a Twilio number or to a number that has been messaging your Twilio number using the [Messages list resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/message#list). You can filter on the number the message was sent to or sent from using [URL parameters](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/message#list-get-filters).

To get all the messages sent to a number in PHP, you can use the [helper library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/php) and this code:

```
// Require composer's autoload to load dependencies. Not required if your environment handles this for you.
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Twilio\Rest\Client;

// Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/user/account
$sid = "your_account_sid"; 
$token = "your_auth_token"; 
$client = new Client($sid, $token);

foreach ($client->account->messages(array('From' => 'NUMBER')) as $message) {
    echo $message->body;
}
```

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: @Philnash..I couldn't find Services folder in twilio..I have installed Twilio throught composer..

Comment: @Philnash..Also what I need is ; If I reply back to a twilio SMS which I received from the twilio generated number say xxxxxxxxxx, I need to get the reply messages in another number (not twilio number) say yyyyyyyyyy..

Comment: Ok, I've updated the answer to reflect how you would use Twilio PHP with composer. If you're looking to get the messages sent from a number that is not a Twilio number, then you need to pass `'From' => "THAT_NUMBER"` as your filter.